# Excel Combine Two Lists - Foreach

Tags: excel

I have a list of students and a list of grades. I want the name of the student repeated in the final list depending on how many grades they have. 
For example:
[image]

I need to create the last two columns, *Finals List Student* and *Final List grade*, **with a function**.

Comment: This sounds very homework-y. Is there a particular part where you are stuck. Have you written any code yet that perhaps we can help you tweak to get to your desired results?

Comment: @JNevill, no. I need a full implementation idea.

Comment: okie doke. When you say "function" are you wanting to do this with a formula, or with a vba function?

Comment: @JNevill, with a formula.